# I get this error when I user dictionary `set value for key`

Tags: ios, objective-c, model, nsdictionary

I get this error when I user dictionary `set value for key`:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionary0 0x6080000120d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key code_type.'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010adc7d4b  **exceptionPreprocess + 171
>
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a05c21e objc_exception_throw + 48
>
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010adc7c99 -[NSException raise] + 9
>
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000109b6a9df -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
>       4   KYGM                                0x000000010826fe5f -[Lucky28BetVC networkForBet] + 1007
>
>       5   KYGM                                0x000000010826f51c -[Lucky28BetVC judgeCondition] + 220
>
>       6   KYGM                                0x000000010826f0da -[Lucky28BetVC betAction:] + 58
>
>       7   UIKit                               0x000000010b1ed8bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
>
>       8   UIKit                               0x000000010b373c38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>
>       9   UIKit                               0x000000010b373f51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
>
>       10  UIKit                               0x000000010b372e4d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
>
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000010b25b545 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
>
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000010b25cc33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
>
>       13  UIKit                               0x000000010b2099ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
>
>       14  UIKit                               0x0000000119de3481 -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 93
>
>       15  UIKit                               0x000000010b9f672d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
>
>       16  UIKit                               0x000000010b9ef463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
>
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad6c761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad5198c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad50e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad50884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
>       21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ed70a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
>       22  UIKit                               0x000000010b1ebc68 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       23  KYGM                                0x000000010825eecf main + 111
>       24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010aa7f68d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My error information is below:

[image]

My code is here:

```
    NSMutableArray *payJsonArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

    for (int i = 0; i < self.dataSource.count; i ++) {

        id model = self.dataSource[i];

        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];

        NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        Lucky28BetCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];

        Lucky28BuyCodeModel *model_temp = (Lucky28BuyCodeModel *)model;

        if ([model_temp.type isEqualToString:@"num"]) {



            [dict setValue:((Lucky28BuyCodeModel *)model).type forKey:@"code_type"];  
            [dict setValue:((Lucky28BuyCodeModel *)model).num forKey:@"codes"];  
            [dict setValue:cell.money_tf.text forKey:@"money"];
            //[dict setValue:((Lucky28BuyCodeModel *)model).num forKey:@"BettingType"];  


        }else {

            [dict setValue:((Lucky28PalyModel *)model).type forKey:@"code_type"];  
            [dict setValue:((Lucky28PalyModel *)model).num forKey:@"codes"];  
            [dict setValue:cell.money_tf.text forKey:@"money"];  // 
        }

        [payJsonArr addObject:dict];
    }
```

My dataSource have two type model:

Lucky28BuyCodeModel:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Lucky28BuyCodeModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *num;  //
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *setting;  // 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *type;  


- (NSComparisonResult)compareBuyCodeModel:(Lucky28BuyCodeModel *)model;

@end
```

And Lucky28PalyModel:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Lucky28PalyModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isSelected; 

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *num;  
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *setting;  
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *type;  

- (NSComparisonResult)compareLucky28PalyModel:(Lucky28PalyModel *)model;

@end
```

How to solve this error in my code?

Comment: `dict` should be a `NSMutableDictionary`, not a `NSDictionary`, and prefer `setObject:forKey:` rather than `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: Use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` if you want to set new value key.

Comment: 1. Change `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary` 2. `((Lucky28PalyModel *)model).type` is int ? if so use it like `@(((Lucky28PalyModel *)model).type) ` so it will be `[dict setValue:@(((Lucky28PalyModel *)model).type) forKey:@"code_type"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two basic errors in your code

first one: you have to use `NSMutableDictionary`, so change the line below

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
```

to

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

then, the second one: you have to use the method `setObject:forKey:` (more at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutabledictionary/1411616-setobject?language=objc)), so you should change the generic line below

```
[dict setValue:((Lucky28BuyCodeModel *)model).type forKey:@"code_type"];
```

to

```
[dict setObject:((Lucky28BuyCodeModel *)model).type forKey:@"code_type"];
```

finally, to "get" you have to use the method `getObjectForKey:` (more at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/1414347-objectforkey?language=objc))

Answer (score 0):

You are using NSDictionary to `setValue:forKey:`, you can not do that, you should use NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
...
```